# Is there any way to recycle colors in 2D animation?

Tags: 2d

There is a problem when coloring in 2D animation.
It's troublesome to recreate the color every time I create a new file.
Can I import the colors after exporting them?
Or can't I register in the Asset Library?
I pressed all the buttons, but I don't think they're there, but I'm asking if I missed something

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save a file with Materials in it, you can [*link*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html#link) to the material from your new file, or [*append*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html#link) it from that file.  The difference is that a link points to the material in the original file; meaning that if you change the material in the original file it will automatically change in any file that links it; but append copies the material so it's now a new material in the new file.

Here's a step by step example:

- Go to the File menu, select *Link*

[image: Selecting Link from the file menu]

- A file browser will appear.  Navigate to the file you want and click on it.  Rather than opening the file, the browser will look something like this:

[image: File browser showing file selected]

- Navigate to Material, go to the material you want and select it.

[image: Selecting a material]

- Click Link.  You will now have the material in your open blend file to use as you want.

Comment: I can use append and link. Thank you for letting me know the difference and attaching a screenshot. Thanks to you, I think I can use the blender without any inconvenience. Have a nice day.